# How do I get wireshark to actually display packets

Tags: wireshark

I've just started using wireshark. I click the blue shark fin, then 10 seconds later click the red stop button. The bar along the bottom of the window says "Packets 47 - Displayed 0".

I can't work out how to actually display packet information. I've tried saving to a file (when I open the file in a text editor I can see bytes of data). I open the file in wireshark, and I still can't see any information about packets - the "No. Time Source Destination etc" columns are all empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately your last paragraph makes this question off-topic here, you could perhaps try http://superuser.com/ instead. But FWIW the most obvious reason for not seeing packets would be that you have a display filter applied, that matches none of the captured packets. Does it say "Apply a display filter" below the blue fin and red stop button, or something else? If it's the latter, try removing that.

Comment: You need to define what traffic you are interested in, and what filters you apply. Wireshark has very good on-line documentation and forums for learning how to use it, but we can't teach you the whole application, and home networking is off-topic here. You are really only going to capture packets to and from your computer, anyway.

Comment: @hertitu - that's really helpful. The display filter box was empty - but clicking the blue arrow at the end of the box has solved my issue - I've now got data displaying. Apologies for being off topic.

Answer (score 3):

There's several thinks that can cause Wireshark to not display packets

The most obvious are :

- capture filter : there's a filter for what wireshark will capture and retain. (seems it's not the case here since you do have something in the pcap file)
- display filter , as commented by hertitu

But it can also be

- incompatible hardware or driver : it has been reported that wireshark doesn't work correctly with some network interface card or drivers
- security software on the host : it has also been reported that windows firewall or some security agents block some traffic before WS handel them
- capturing encrypted Wifi data (WEP / WPA(2)) : if you capture data over a Wireless interface, Wireshark will see the bit flow but cannot decrypt it and will not display anything.

If you are on a wired interface you could try booting on a USB stick with a live linux install and perform a tcpdump on the interface to see if you have better results.

Comment: Thanks @JFL really helpful +1 from me (I think I just needed to click the blue arrow button at the end of the display filter box).